# How to sum past 30 days consecutively?

Tags: mysql, sum

I need help adapting this query, to sum past 30 days consecutively. For example, sum today + 29 days, than yesterday + the 29 days before yesterday and so on ...

Here is what I got for today + the past 29 days:

```
SELECT sum(revenue) as total_revenue
FROM sales
WHERE date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 30)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

If you want a 30-day moving average, here is one approach using a correlated subquery:

```
select date,
       (select sum(revenue)
        from sales s2
        where datediff(s2.date, s.date) between 0 and 30
       ) revenue_30days
from sales s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this? I think correlated sub-query is slow...

```
SELECT s1.date, SUM(s2.revenue)
FROM (
    SELECT date
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY date
) s1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT date, SUM(revenue) AS revenue
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY date
) s2
WHERE s2.date BETWEEN s1.date AND s1.date + INTERVAL 30 DAY AND s1.date
GROUP BY s1.date;
```

## Performance Test

I have tested `correlated sub-subquery` and `sub-query and JOIN`
If I have mistakes, please advise me.

Both Q1 (correlated sub-query) and Q2 (sub-query and JOIN) return same result. You can test here. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e66a9/6

### Summary

- Q1 (correlated sub-query) : **1 hour 28 min 33.67 sec**
- Q2 (sub-query and JOIN) : **0.14 sec**

### Test Environment

- MySQL 5.5
- CentOS 5.3 64bit
- TPC-H `orders` table (contains 3M rows)

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `o_orderkey` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `o_custkey` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `o_orderstatus` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `o_totalprice` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `o_orderDATE` date NOT NULL,
  `o_orderpriority` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `o_clerk` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `o_shippriority` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `o_comment` varchar(79) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`o_orderkey`),
  KEY `o_custkey` (`o_custkey`),
  KEY `o_orderDATE` (`o_orderDATE`),
  CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`o_custkey`) REFERENCES `customer` (`c_custkey`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

### Total COUNT

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*) FROM orders;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|  3000000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.51 sec)
```

### Row COUNT Between 1992-01-01 and 1992-01-31

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders o WHERE o.o_orderDATE BETWEEN '1992-01-01' AND '1992-01-31';
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|    38618 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

### Q1 (1 hour 28 min 33.67 sec)

<strike>Unfortunately Q1 never stop :-( I haved killed it after 10 minutes</strike> I've got the result after having meeting. It took 1h 28m

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT o_orderDATE,
       (SELECT SUM(o_totalprice)
        FROM orders o2
        WHERE DATEDIFF(o2.o_orderDATE, o.o_orderDATE) BETWEEN 0 AND 29
          AND o2.o_orderDATE BETWEEN '1992-01-01' AND '1992-03-01'
       ) revenue_30days
FROM orders o
WHERE o.o_orderDATE BETWEEN '1992-01-01' AND '1992-01-31';

+-------------+----------------+
| o_orderDATE | revenue_30days |
+-------------+----------------+
| 1992-01-01  |  5648795149.74 |
| 1992-01-02  |  5649262055.28 |
| 1992-01-03  |  5666711554.48 |
| 1992-01-04  |  5677697387.74 |
| 1992-01-05  |  5676650777.36 |
| 1992-01-06  |  5669275725.69 |
| 1992-01-07  |  5692730838.47 |
| 1992-01-08  |  5688570035.24 |
| 1992-01-09  |  5684709644.40 |
| 1992-01-10  |  5688857031.75 |
| 1992-01-11  |  5676182193.32 |
| 1992-01-12  |  5683115775.20 |
| 1992-01-13  |  5670141469.02 |
| 1992-01-14  |  5684636532.16 |
| 1992-01-15  |  5683027972.67 |
| 1992-01-16  |  5670511926.85 |
| 1992-01-17  |  5674076998.82 |
| 1992-01-18  |  5668348303.38 |
| 1992-01-19  |  5674735578.96 |
| 1992-01-20  |  5689425729.08 |
| 1992-01-21  |  5686550437.68 |
| 1992-01-22  |  5684366682.26 |
| 1992-01-23  |  5679647411.20 |
| 1992-01-24  |  5676757491.15 |
| 1992-01-25  |  5679641366.53 |
| 1992-01-26  |  5685238563.41 |
| 1992-01-27  |  5691828747.39 |
| 1992-01-28  |  5695307116.83 |
| 1992-01-29  |  5687069527.23 |
| 1992-01-30  |  5683190558.58 |
| 1992-01-31  |  5686476320.12 |
+-------------+----------------+
31 rows in set (1 hour 28 min 33.67 sec)
```

### Q2 (0.01 sec)

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE o1.o_orderDATE, SUM(o2.o_totalprice)
FROM (
    SELECT o_orderDATE
    FROM orders
    WHERE o_orderDATE BETWEEN '1992-01-01' AND '1992-01-31'
    GROUP BY o_orderDATE
) o1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT o_orderDATE, SUM(o_totalprice) AS o_totalprice
    FROM orders
    WHERE o_orderDATE BETWEEN '1992-01-01' AND '1992-03-01'
    GROUP BY o_orderDATE
) o2
WHERE o2.o_orderDATE BETWEEN o1.o_orderDATE AND o1.o_orderDATE + INTERVAL 29 DAY AND o1.o_orderDATE
GROUP BY o1.o_orderDATE;
+-------------+----------------------+
| o_orderDATE | SUM(o2.o_totalprice) |
+-------------+----------------------+
| 1992-01-01  |        5648795149.74 |
| 1992-01-02  |        5649262055.28 |
| 1992-01-03  |        5666711554.48 |
| 1992-01-04  |        5677697387.74 |
| 1992-01-05  |        5676650777.36 |
| 1992-01-06  |        5669275725.69 |
| 1992-01-07  |        5692730838.47 |
| 1992-01-08  |        5688570035.24 |
| 1992-01-09  |        5684709644.40 |
| 1992-01-10  |        5688857031.75 |
| 1992-01-11  |        5676182193.32 |
| 1992-01-12  |        5683115775.20 |
| 1992-01-13  |        5670141469.02 |
| 1992-01-14  |        5684636532.16 |
| 1992-01-15  |        5683027972.67 |
| 1992-01-16  |        5670511926.85 |
| 1992-01-17  |        5674076998.82 |
| 1992-01-18  |        5668348303.38 |
| 1992-01-19  |        5674735578.96 |
| 1992-01-20  |        5689425729.08 |
| 1992-01-21  |        5686550437.68 |
| 1992-01-22  |        5684366682.26 |
| 1992-01-23  |        5679647411.20 |
| 1992-01-24  |        5676757491.15 |
| 1992-01-25  |        5679641366.53 |
| 1992-01-26  |        5685238563.41 |
| 1992-01-27  |        5691828747.39 |
| 1992-01-28  |        5695307116.83 |
| 1992-01-29  |        5687069527.23 |
| 1992-01-30  |        5683190558.58 |
| 1992-01-31  |        5686476320.12 |
+-------------+----------------------+
31 rows in set (0.14 sec)
```

### EXPLAIN of Q1

```
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                     |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | o     | range | o_orderDATE   | o_orderDATE | 3       | NULL |  75702 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | o2    | range | o_orderDATE   | o_orderDATE | 3       | NULL | 147522 | Using where                               |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
```

### EXPLAIN of Q2

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL |     31 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL |     61 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
|  3 | DERIVED     | orders     | range | o_orderDATE   | o_orderDATE | 3       | NULL | 147522 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | orders     | range | o_orderDATE   | o_orderDATE | 3       | NULL |      5 | Using where; Using index for group-by        |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

### Q2 with entire rows (8.87 secs)

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE o1.o_orderDATE, SUM(o2.o_totalprice)
FROM (
    SELECT o_orderDATE
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY o_orderDATE
) o1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT o_orderDATE, SUM(o_totalprice) AS o_totalprice
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY o_orderDATE
) o2
GROUP BY o1.o_orderDATE;
```